# How do I close the Filtrify panel when opening another?

Tags: javascript, css, filtering

I'm currently using the beautiful Filtrify script of a website of mine with Isotope integration (http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/).

On my site I have 4 "categories"/panels for searching my  -field. When I open the first category/panel and hover the mouse over to the next one, and open it, the first one is still open. Is it possible, with CSS or Javascript, to close a opened Filtrify panel when hovering over to the next category/button to open another Filtrify panel? Now the just remains open if I open them all. For an example, open "genre", "main actors" and "director" here: http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/movies.html

Would really appreciate your help! Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 3):

I do not know in depth the library, but you could try to close the siblings of a panel before opening another panel.

a first approximation of the method could be:

```
Filtrify.prototype.closeSiblingsPanel = function ( f ) {
    for(var item in this._menu){
        if(item !== f && this._menu[item].panel){
            this._menu[item].panel.addClass("ft-hidden");
            this._menu[item].label.removeClass("ft-opened");
        }
    }
};
```

you also have to modify the click event handler:

```
Filtrify.prototype.events = function ( f ) {
    //...
    this._menu[f].label.on("click", this._bind(function(event){
        this.openPanel( f );
        this.closeSiblingsPanel( f );
        this.bringToFront( f );
        event.stopPropagation();
    }, this) );
    //...
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but I'm not familiar with javascript at all, can you help me where to put it?