# jQuery Filtrify Plugin - filter "or" instead of "and"

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Check this out: http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/movies.html

If I choose `Genre: Action` and `Main Actors: Aaron Eckhart`, It shows the movies that their genre is Action, and also their main actor is Aaron Eckhart. (in this case: "The Dark Knight")

Till now it's all good. But if I choose for example `Genre: Action, Animation` (both of them), it's also shows only one movie, that meets **both of the conditions**.

What I want is that if I choose multiple values in one "parent" (genre etc.), it'll do an "or" condition, and not "and" condition.

For example, if I choose `Genre: action`, `Main Actors: Aaron Eckhart, Aaron Johnson` it'll show:

```
genre: action
AND
main actors: (Aaron Eckhart OR Aaron Johnson)
```

(^ it's not a code...)

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $.filtrify("container", "placeHolder");
});
```

```
<ul id="container">
    <li data-genre="Drama, Sci-Fi, Thriller" data-main-actors="Harrison Ford, Rutger Hauer, Sean Young, Edward James Olmos" data-director="Ridley Scott"> ... Blade Runner ... </li>
    <li data-genre="Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller" data-main-actors="Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Ken Watanabe, Liam Neeson" data-director="Christopher Nolan"> ... Batman Begins ... </li>
    <li data-genre="Drama" data-main-actors="Mark Wahlberg, Julianne Moore, Burt Reynolds, Luis GuzmÃ¡n" data-director="Paul Thomas Anderson"> ... Boogie Nights ... </li>
    <li data-genre="Action, Adventure" data-main-actors="Harrison Ford, Sean Connery, Alison Doody, Denholm Elliott" data-director="Steven Spielberg"> ... Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade ... </li>
    <li data-genre="Crime, Mystery, Thriller" data-main-actors="Harvey Keitel, Tim Roth, Michael Madsen, Chris Penn" data-director="Quentin Tarantino"> ... Reservoir Dogs ... </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Thank you,
and sorry for my English

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What's the connection? it's different

Comment: Where is relevant code? EDIT: ha, ok filtrify is a plugin

Comment: @Ariel, indeed the difference is clearer after your edit. Apologies, close vote retracted.

Comment: After checking github page, i don't see any option for that. You could pull a request to let author knows what could be a new feature for this plugin. I guess, should not be so hard(???) to modify plugin to get this behaviour

Answer (score 3):

It is actually quite simple:
in the Filtrify.prototype.filter function in filtrify.js, replace:

```
if ( !this._query[f].length  || c >= this._query[f].length ) {
```

with:

```
if ( !this._query[f].length  || c >= 1 ) {
```

this will effect the OR condition for the field tag filtering, but it conserves the AND condition between fields.

Then to keep the field count unchanged (if you keep it as is, it will be confusing for the user because it is not anymore an AND condition), in the Filtrify.prototype.updateFields function in filtrify.js, change:

```
if( match && tags ) {
```

with

```
if( tags ) {
```

If you're also trying to display one panel at a time, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233423/how-do-i-close-the-filtrify-panel-when-opening-another) has the solution...

Hope this helps...